# Cannot connect to mysql

Tags: windows, mysql

Recently I have moved the data folder of MySql to the other folder as describe in the **my.ini** following:

```
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket= "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="D:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir="D:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir="I:/Dropbox/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
innodb_force_recovery = 4
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 1
```

However, I can't start mysql via XAMPP Control Panel. The following are the contents of two files: **Elvis.err** and **mysql_error.log**.

```
120819 20:12:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120819 20:12:28  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120819 20:12:28  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120819 20:12:28  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
120819 20:12:28  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
120819 20:12:31  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 7527526
120819 20:12:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120819 20:12:31 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.8'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

The content of **mysql_error.log**

```
120819 20:12:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120819 20:12:24  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
120819 20:12:24  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120819 20:12:24  InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: File name G:\Dropbox\mysql\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I need to treat two issues. These are:

1. From the terminal, I run mysqld in D:\xampp\mysql\bin. Then start mysql using XAMPP control panel. It works well.
2. In fact, I changed the data folder to **I:/Dropbox/mysql/data** but mysql has still informed an error to be not created in G: that moved before.

And my questions:
How can I configure mysql can be moved the data folder to new folder?

I am appreciated for all helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. Are you running this on your own server or a hosted server?

Comment: I just run it on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

> InnoDB: File name G:\Dropbox\mysql\data\ibdata1

Are you trying to store your MySQL data files on a file sharing service?

I would suggest that this is *highly inadvisable* given that both the DBMS and the file sharing service will want to make low-level changes to the binary data files, leaving you wide open to database corruption.

Store the data files as "close" as possible to the process that manipulates them, i.e. the database server process.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:

> "InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation."

Then:

```
redmachine ~ # perror 3
OS error code   3:  No such process
```

Permissions need to be as the old folder, and the directory structure as in the old data folder. It looks like you might also need to repair some tables there.

Have a look at this post on mysql lists: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/100211